# Setup ktor in kmm with android's network_security_config file

Tags: ktor, kmm, android-network-security-config

I’m integrating the certificate pinning to the ktor kmm
Does ktor use network_security_config file in android or we have to setup with below code programmatically?

```
actual class Test actual constructor() {
    actual val httpClientEngine: HttpClientEngineFactory<HttpClientEngineConfig>
        get() = OkHttp
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Ktor engines for Android ([CIO](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#cio), [OkHttp](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#okhttp), [Android](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#android)) use [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).